# How to show/hide React element of fetched array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to show/hide a part of JSX depending on `onClickShowChart` state property and output the correct chart data based on the ID.

But this part inside a map loop, when i click to show element then it will fetch the data based on the ID then return back to array and show the chart.

**Challenge**:
The problem is every time i click to show the chart, every mapped items will shown up the same chart data, because it's depending on the same state property. I can't set individual state because it is using `array.map()` function to loop all records.

How do I show/hide the correct chart data individually without effect and preserve other record state and chart data?

```js
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Initial states
    this.state = { dataList[], showChart: false, showChartData: [] }
 }

componentWillmount() {
 this._getDataList()
}

 _getDataList() {
      axios.get(`.../List`,
        {
          params: { id: id },
          headers: { 'Authorization': ...accessToken }
        }).then((res) => {
          this.setState({ dataList: res.data })
        })
   })

 onClickShowChart = (id) => {
    this.setState({ showChart: true }, () => this._getGraphData(id))
 }

 // When click to show, it will fetch graph data and then pass to state
 _getGraphData(id) {
      axios.get(`.../productAdsStatistic`,
        {
          params: { id: id },
          headers: { 'Authorization': ...accessToken }
        }).then((res) => {
          this.setState({ graphData: res.data })
        })
   })

 renderChart() {
    return (
      <Chart data={this.state.graphData}>
       // ...
      </Chart>
    )
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <Row>
         <Col>
           {this.state.dataList.map((v) => {
             <h1>{v.title}<h1>
             <span onClick={() => this.onClickShowChart(v._id)}>
               Click to show chart
             </span>
             <Row>
               <Col>{this.state.showChart === true ? renderChart() : ''}</Col>
             </Row>
           }
         </Col>
       </Row>
     </div>
   }
 }
```

JSON Array result from API

```sh
[
 {
  _id: C1,
  title: Chart A
 },
 {
  _id: C2,
  title: Chart B
 }
]
```

Graph Data JSON Array result from API for 1 chart

```sh
[
  {
    month: "Jan",
    value: 7
  },
  {
    month: "Feb",
    value: 6.9
  }
]
```

Comment: Just mantain a separate state variable which will store the index of  item in dataList which got clicked. and renderChart should accept one argument corresponding to the rowIndex. in renderChart function compare the rowIndex and above state variable, if it matches, render the chart, else null.

Comment: Are you going to show one chart at a time? Or it will show as you click then keep that item shown even if click on the different one?

Comment: It will keeps that item shown even click on different one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follwing is the sandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-snow-ne0gv?file=/src/DataList.js

Class version of the above solution:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-dream-xy3vm

Expanding the idea whatever I have mentioned in comments: Just mantain a separate state variable which will store the indices of item in dataList which got clicked. and renderChart should accept one argument corresponding to the rowIndex. in renderChart function check the rowIndex exists in above state indices array, if it's there, render the chart, else null.

Comment: When i click to show chart, it will trigger _getGraphData() function to fetch new set of data from chart API.

Comment: You can pass the property to Chart component the id of the clicked item in dataList, then that id will help you to fetch a particular Chart data in _getGraphData function.

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly, please check now.

Comment: If i click to show chart, it will keeps that item shown even click on different one but can also hide the specific one like toggle to show/hide that item.

Comment: @android1751 I have added the toggling behaviour can you check now.

Comment: @android1751 Please check the answer now, it has the Class Version avilable.

Comment: Now i can click to show and hide the particular chart but now the chart data is changing based on the item id even click on different one. The chart data is depending on `<Chart data={this.state.graphData}>
</Chart>`.

Comment: In that case create a graphData State and store it in the array. for each index a sepearete data can be stored in that way.